# Having trouble with cloth physics

Tags: modeling, cloth-simulation

So, I've followed a couple of tutorials about cloths, and I wanted to make a kind of rolled around cloak. Thing is, it passes through most of the mesh besides that hole I made for the head. I don't really know/have found out why yet this happens, so here's hoping that some of you people can help me.

Here's all the info I thought you might need. [image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Has the Transformer / robot _Collision_ enabled? Looks like it's not really a collision object for the cloth.

Comment: best help you can give us is provide your blend file

Comment: Cloth on the cloth, Collision on the robot. It looks like you’re mixing them.

Comment: Here's the blend file https://pasteall.org/blend/1c67540551864bcb9e82a80b4f790a45 . I thought collision needed to be on both, isn't that right?